# Does BigQuery charge for querying only the stream buffer?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a day partitioned table with approx 300k rows in the streaming buffer.  When running an interactive, non-cached, standard SQL query using 
`SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE _PARTITIONTIME IS NULL`

The query validator says:
`Valid: This query will process 0 B when run.`

And after executing, the job information tab says:

`Bytes Processed  0 B
Bytes Billed    0 B`

The query is certainly returning real-time results each time I run it.  Is this actually a free operation?

Comment: Logically it should not charge us, as those records are in tranzit, they do not count against the storage, as they were not persisted yet. But eventually an official answer would be good. I suggest wait 2-3 days then create an issue. There you are guaranteed to get an answer form the BQ team. https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers