# why does query from streaming buffer doesn't get billed

Tags: google-bigquery

When the query contains a reference to only data from stream buffer, the query returns the results correctly but doesn't show any bytes billed,  any links that explain this behavior/ confirm would be helpful

Comment: Can you provide sql example, result and execution plan data

Comment: Seems this has been already asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47911221/does-bigquery-charge-for-querying-only-the-stream-buffer

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link,  seem to be open ended though

Answer (score 0):

Last year, we've been confirmed that Data accumulated in the streaming buffer is not calculated towards "bytes processed" and therefore not billed.

It's unknown if the BigQuery team will change this, but since data usually doesn't stay in the buffer for long (typically less than 90 minutes, and much less if you stream at high rate), then maybe this behavior will stay this way for some time.

Just keep in mind that once data is moved to the permanent storage, all subsequent queries reading that data will report bytes processed and bill accordingly.